# Xamarin custom controls

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile

I am new to Xamarin.I decided my first project to be a fitness app.I wanted to have a custom control , an image with a button and a label inside of it , so I did this in a content view file:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Fitness_App.TabWorkout">
    <RelativeLayout >
        <Image x:Name="img" Source="workout"/>
        <Button BackgroundColor= "Wheat"
                CornerRadius="30"
                WidthRequest="50"
                HeightRequest="50"
                RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=img, Property=Width, Factor=0.68}"
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=img, Property=Height, Factor=0.45}"/>
         <Label x:Name="workout_name"
                FontFamily="BebasNeue"
                TextColor ="ForestGreen"
                FontSize="37"
                RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=img, Property=Width, Factor=0.18}"
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=img, Property=Height, Factor=0.2}"/>
                
    </RelativeLayout>

</ContentView>
```

And since I want 5 workouts(for 5 muscle groups) , I put this inside my page:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
            <ScrollView>
                <StackLayout>
                    <local:TabWorkout/>
                    <local:TabWorkout/>
                    <local:TabWorkout/>
                    <local:TabWorkout/>
                    <local:TabWorkout/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </ContentPage.Content>
```

and this is how it looks:
[android simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiHWr.png)
I have read about bindable properties but I don't know how they would help me in this case.I don't know why the width of my image is not full.When I have just placed images in my stacklayout , it seemed to work.Maybe you guys have another idea for this?thanks.

Comment: you have not specified any `HorizontalOption` values on any elements in your layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have read about bindable properties but I don't know how they would help me in this case.

Here we add bindable property for the `Image` control , the same way to the `Label`.

1. Define `BindableProperty` in custom control .
2. Set the image source in `propertyChanged` callback .
3. Assign the value in xaml .

   ```
   [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class TabWorkout : ContentView
    {
        public TabWorkout()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty ImageNameProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("ImageName", typeof(string), typeof(TabWorkout), propertyChanged: OnEventNameChanged);

        public string ImageName
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ImageNameProperty); }
            set {
                SetValue(ImageNameProperty, value);
            }

        }

        static void OnEventNameChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            if(newValue != null)
            {
                var control = (TabWorkout)bindable;
                control.img.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(newValue as string);
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   ```
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <local:TabWorkout ImageName="a.jpg"/>
            <local:TabWorkout ImageName="b.png"/>
            <local:TabWorkout ImageName="c.png"/>
            <local:TabWorkout ImageName="d.png"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
   ```

> I don't know why the width of my image is not full.

Set `Aspect` to `Fill` should be able to solve the problem .

```
 <Image x:Name="img" Aspect="Fill"/>
```

#### Update

For bindable property , you can not only assign the value directly like normal property field but also create binding on it .

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
        <local:TabWorkout ImageName="{Binding ImageName}"/>
        <local:TabWorkout ImageName="a.jpg"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This is awesome, thanks!But I still can't see the use of bindable properties...Can't you just declare a normal property field public ImageName and customize your setter?

Comment: Check my update .